# Microsoft Azure Devops Hosted agent images not working

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Microsoft Azure Devops Hosted agent images not working. The Docker container is unable to connect to the SAAS version of azure devops from this morning

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent-docker

Does any one have the same issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The VSTS Agent Docker is Deprecated:

[image]

You'll need to switch to the `microsoft-azure-pipelines-vsts-agent` image instead.

Comment: Is this a docker image ? or i need to build the vm with packer?

Comment: @krishnam Yes, this answer is valid. VSTS agent Docker images are deprecated (hence obsoleted).